# identifying Duplicates and flag the duplicate

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Suppose if i have list `input_list=["Name","Age","Address","nAme","Father","NAME","AGE"]`

- I have `"name"` multiple times but while checking I don't want it to be case sensitive.
  if there is duplicate add 1 , 2 etc.
- I am trying to remove Duplicates i want to add `NaMe`, `Name1`,`NAME2`
  but order should be same

  can you please help me achieve this output.

I want output `final_list=["Name","Age","Address","nAme1","Father","NAME2","AGE1"]`

Comment: I think this was closed in error - OP doesn't want to remove duplicates but rename them (appending a number). The post perhaps should make this clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

1. Make a set of lowercased entries from that list

```py
lowered_set = {word.lower() for word in input_list}
```

2. Make a dict with that set as keys

```py
occurrences = {word: 0 for word in lowered_set}
```

3. Walk the input_list, append count if the word was used already, and increment the count:

```py
output_list = []
for word in input_list:
    lowered = word.lower()
    previous = occurrences[lowered]
    occurrences[lowered] += 1
    if previous:
        output_list.append(f"{word}{previous}")
    else:
        output_list.append(word)
```

There's surely a better way, though

Comment: (this doesn't work if your input_list has words ending with numbers… `["name", "nAmE1", "NAME", "namE"]` will become `["name", "nAmE1", "NAME1", "namE2"]`